# WP7 Datepicker minumum, maximum date?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to set these 2? for example credit card expiredate is good example for that? If I can enter minumum selectable date, I can prevent user to select dates in the past?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is currently not implemented. but you can download the source at http://silverlight.codeplex.com/ and modify the classes for your needs.